# Should we Use Tag or Object ID to differentiate 2 different Control in an Application in Xcode and IPhone Development

Tags: iphone, xcode

Which one is the preferred way? Both are just number right?

Comment: do you mean by Object ID like `(IBAction)showPicker:(id)sender;`?

Comment: I mean the one in identity inspector when we select a view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on what you want to accomplish.

1.Tag - is not unique and is set up by you. Good thing about it is that it does not change from session to session.

**EDIT:**

2.Object ID - is unique, and is only used by IB internally. You don't have an access to this property from code. If you even try to change it in IB it will not let you. I was actually wondering why it is even visible.

Comment: So in most cases I would use Tags

Comment: In all cases you would use tag.